# When I press Ctrl+. the emoji popup does not show up in ubuntu

Tags: emoji

I recently dual booted my pc with ubuntu and I was surprised how faster ubuntu is when compared to windows. I really like ubuntu and I have been using it for quite a long time now.
I am having problem with emojis on ubuntu where if i press Ctrl+. the emoji popup does not show up in any other app other than the system apps. I this in ubuntu text editor  the emoji popup showed up but in any other app that i use for example signal then I am not able to get the  emoji popup and every time i need to use the emoji keyboard of the signal if i want to send emojis in text. I have also tried ctrl+shift+e but still it only work in system apps.
Any help would be great thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Linux is composed of free software, and although distributions manage remarkably well to give it all a consistent look, there is a very large diversity between different applications. They may use very different libraries, e.g. QT versus GTK, and then, even within a toolkit, some applications may still use the old GTK2 toolkit, others GTK3 and currently GTK4 is coming in.

That is why this <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> shortcut key to insert emojis only work in a specific set of applications, in particular GTK based applications that use the GTL libraries to render their text. There are some alternative options to insert emoji in applications:

- Enter your character in for example the text editor, then copy paste it elsewhere
- Use the Characters tool. You can search characters, e.g. "smiley". Clicking pops up a dialog: with a click on enter, you copy the character to the clipboard. For quick access, you could load it with a custom shortcut key.

Answer (score 0):

In the utilities folder of Applications, there is an app called Characters. It consists of many emojis and their uni-codes. Open that app and copy the emoji using the provided button and paste it wherever you wanted.

The reason Ctrl + . won't work is the incompatibility of some third party apps with Ubuntu's stock libraries.

Hope this helps... :)